# How to make my comboboxes stop autochanging values

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

couldn't find an answer to my issue. So hoped someone could help. I have to comboboxes on one form, and they are both filled with data from the same datatable. The issue is that when I select i.e. first value of combobox1, it automatically sets combobox2 the same value. I would like to be able to select two different values and don't know where is my issue.

```
private void CardWords_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        try
        {        
            this.comboBox1.DataSource = this.dataSet.Tables["Languages"];
            //this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(this.dataSet.Languages.ToArray());
            this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Language";
            this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "LanguageId";
            this.comboBox1.BindingContext = this.BindingContext;
            //this.comboBox2.Items.AddRange(this.dataSet.Languages.ToArray());
            this.comboBox2.DataSource = this.dataSet.Tables["Languages"];
            this.comboBox2.DisplayMember = "Language";
            this.comboBox2.ValueMember = "LanguageId";
            this.comboBox2.BindingContext = this.BindingContext;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }            
        

    }
```

When I set the items it works, but then I want to be able to use LanguageID column as value.

Comment: Have you considered making two (2) data sources? One for each combo box?

Comment: You can copy the DataTable (e.g., use the `CopyToDataTable()` extension method) or generate a Table from its DefaultView (`ToTable()`). What is the actual use of these ComboBoxes? What else uses the `Languages` Table? Is this supposed to pick two different languages from a collection? To then do what with what, precisely?

Comment: @Jimi Yes, it's supposed to let you pick two languages. You pick one language in one combobox and the other one in the second one. After you pick the languages you can add a new translation and then it adds the new words, to a different table.

Comment: @JohnG I don't get what you mean by making two datasources. I tried making two DataSets and assigning a different one two each of the comboboxes datasources. I will try copying the table.

Comment: So, you just need the SelectedValue of the ComboBoxes' selections. As mentioned, just duplicate the DataTable. -- I asked what the use of the ComboBox control because you're probably trying to bind the results to two different Columns of another source of data (you didn't specify what that is). Use DataBindings to bind the SelectedValue of each ComboBox to the other data source. -- You can remove: `this.comboBox1.BindingContext = this.BindingContext;`

Comment: @Jimi ok, so copying the table didn't work, but generating the table seems to have worked. Could You maybe explain, why this way allows to select two different values? I want to understand what was wrong previously. Thanks though :)

Comment: Each form has a BindingContext which has a CurrencyManager. So all controls would have the same position for the same datasource. Try create a new BindingContext for one of your comboboxes. See also [BindingContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingcontext.-ctor?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @Steeeve Ok, now I get it. Thanks :) Have a great day

Comment: If both combo boxes contain the same data source, then “each” combo box is “tied” to the same data source… so… when one combo box value gets changed, this event gets triggered down to the data source, which in turn fires the other combo box to follow suit. The fix is to simply separate the data sources.

Comment: However depending on how the combo boxes are used and if the combo boxes do not necessarily “need” a data source… then it is also possible to “manually” add the items to each combo box. In other words, make a method that takes a `ComboBox` and a `DataTable`, then loop through the data table and “manually” add the items to the combo box. You could then use the method to fill both combo boxes with the same data table and they would be independent of each other. This may lower some overhead as you don’t have to keep two duplicate data sources.

Comment: Yes, you can also use two BindingContext objects. But, as already mentioned and asked, this depends on the use of these Controls. If you have another source of data that makes use of these selections, you may have a hard time making use of two BindingContexts (e.g., when there's a DataGridView that receives the selections); it may be simpler to use different data sources and use DataBindings to synchronize, eventually. But, it all depends on the use case, which is not exactly clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, maybe you shouldn't put everything in one procedure. Apart from that this would help you to understand the cause of your problem, it will also enable you to reuse the code, to unit test it, and if needed change it without having to change a lot of code.

First of all, apparently your Form has to display "an item selected from a list of similar items, together with a visual possibility to select another item". It has to display this twice. This means that you need two of these objects. One may have selected item X, the other object has selected item Y. That both objects have the same collection of items to choose from does not influence this.

### Quick and easy method

The easy method is to use the common source data to create two BindingLists, and assign each BindingList to one ComboBox.

**Advantages**: Quick to implement, easy to use. Easy to change if you want to change it later (ComboBoxes show different collections).

**Disadvantages**: less efficient, you will have one collection containing the common source data per ComboBox. You have to unit test this once per ComboBox. You will have have a copy-paste solution, which might be error prone if in future you will add a third ComboBox.

Let's say these ComboBoxes will both show the same sequence of objects of type `MyItem`. ComboBox1 will select `Item1`; ComboBox2 will select `Item2`. So both Item1 and Item2 will be of type MyItem.

The solution will have procedures like this:

```
// returns the sequence of items to display in the comboBoxes
private IEnumerable<MyItem> GetSourceData() {...}

// Get / Set the source data in ComboBox1
private BindingList<MyItem> DisplayData1
{
    get => (BindingList<MyItem>)this.ComboBox1.DataSource;
    set => this.ComboBox1.DataSource = value;
}

private MyItem SelectedItem1
{
    get => (MyItem)this.ComboBox1.SelectedItem;
    set => this.ComboBox1.SelectedItem = value;
}
```

You need similar methods for ComboBox2.

```
private void InitComboBoxes()
{
    IEnumerable<MyItem> commonComboBoxData = this.GetSourceData();
    this.DisplayData1 = new BindingList<MyItem>(commonComboBoxData.ToList());
    this.DisplayData2 = new BindingList<MyItem>(commonComboBoxData.ToList());
}
```

If the operator indicates that he has finished selecting the items in the ComboBoxes, for instance by pressing the *Apply Now* button:

```
private void OnButtonApplyNow_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    MyItem selected1 = this.SelectedItem1;
    MyItem selected2 = this.SelectedItem2;
    ProcessSelectedItems(selected1, selected2);
}
```

That's it. Only a few one-liner methods.

### The neat solution: create a special UserControl

Although the previous solution would work. it would be a hell of a job if you need 10 such ComboBoxes in your form, or if you need to do this on five forms.

The neat solution would be to create a UserControl that contains a ComboBox, which allows you to set the common source data and get the selected item.

To be better reusable, this UserControl will be a generic class that will show items of type `T`

Use visual studio designer to create a UserControl that contains a Docked ComboBox.

You could derive from ComboBox instead of use composition, but that would give users of your class access to properties that you don't want them to. After all you don't want allow users of your class to put `Customers` in the DataSource of a ComboBox that should show `Products`.

```
class MyComboBox<T> : UserControl         // TODO: invent a proper name
{
    // constructor and comboBox1 added by designer
    private MyComboBox() {...}
    private ComboBox comboBox1 = ...
```

Add the methods above:

```
    private BindingList<T> DisplayedItems
    {
        get => (BindingList<T>)this.ComboBox1.DataSource;
        set => this.ComboBox1.DataSource = value;
    }

    private T SelectedItem
    {
        get => (T)this.ComboBox1.SelectedItem;
        set => this.ComboBox1.SelectedItem = value;
    }
```

You will also need to tell which property of type T should be displayed.

```
    public string DisplayMember
    {
        get => this.comboBox1.DisplayMember;
        set => this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = value;
    }
```

After compiling you can use visual studio designer to add `MyComboBox` to your Forms, similar to how you would add a Button

Usage: using visual studio designer you have added 10 ComboBoxes, who will all show items of type `Product`. The first five ComboBoxes will show the product's `Name`, four ComboBoxes will show the `Id` of the Product, and one ComboBox will show the `Price`.

```
public MyClass() // constructor
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Comboboxes that show the name
    this.ComboName1.DisplayMember = nameof(Product.Name);
    this.ComboName2.DisplayMember = nameof(Product.Name);
    this.ComboName3.DisplayMember = nameof(Product.Name);
    this.ComboName4.DisplayMember = nameof(Product.Name);
    this.ComboName5.DisplayMember = nameof(Product.Name);

    // ComboBoxes that show the Id:
    this.ComboId1.DisplayMember = nameof(Product.Id);
    this.ComboId2.DisplayMember = nameof(Product.Id);
    this.ComboId3.DisplayMember = nameof(Product.Id);
    this.ComboId4.DisplayMember = nameof(Product.Id);

    // ComboBox that shows the Price:
    this.ComboPrice1.DisplayMember = nameof(Product.Price);
}
```

Initialize the ComboBoxes:

```
private void InitComboboxes
{
    IEnumerable<Product> selectableProducts = GetSelectableProducts();

    var comboBoxesToInit = new MyComboBox<Product>[]
    {
        this.ComboName1, this.ComboName2, ..., this.ComboPrice;
    };

    foreach (MyComboBox comboBoxToInit in comboBoxesToInit)
    {
       comboBoxToInit.DisplayedItems = new BindingList<Product>(selectableProducts.ToList());
    };
```

Do some testing: what happens if you convert the selecatableProducts to a List only once:

```
List<Product> selectableProducts = GetSelectableProducts().ToList();
foreach(...)
{
    comboBoxToInit.DisplayedItems = new BindingList<Product>(selectableProducts);
```

Maybe we are lucky and this works also.